# Find rows for a particular date in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

I need to write a SQL statement to find the drinker, order date and total number of drinks
ordered by each drinker in a same day. Then I need to display the results in the descending order of total number of drinks, then in the ascending order of drinker.

I am a little confused as to what the question is asking me to do. I am very new to SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

Select:

```
SELECT DRINKER, ODATE, COUNT(DRINK)
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY DRINKER, ODATE, DRINK
ORDER BY DRINKER ASC, DRINK DESC;
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ALLDRINKS(  /* All legal drinks */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
    CONSTRAINT DRINKNAME_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINK) );

CREATE TABLE DRINKERS ( /* All drinkers */
DRINKER VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DRINKERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (DRINKER));

CREATE TABLE LOCATED(   /* Pubs have locations */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
STREET      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Street name  */
BLDG_NO     DECIMAL(4)  NOT NULL,   /* Building number  */
    CONSTRAINT LOCATED_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(PUB) );

CREATE TABLE SERVES(    /* Pubs serve drinks */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
PRICE       DECIMAL(5,2)    NOT NULL,   /* Drink price  */
    CONSTRAINT SERVES_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(PUB, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT SERVES_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB) 
    REFERENCES LOCATED(PUB),
    CONSTRAINT SERVES_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINK)
    REFERENCES ALLDRINKS(DRINK)  );

CREATE TABLE LIKES( /* Drinkers like drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
RATING      DECIMAL(1)  NOT NULL,   /* Rating of the drink  */
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(DRINK) REFERENCES ALLDRINKS(DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_DKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER)); 

CREATE TABLE ORDERS(    /* Drinkers visit pubs and consumes drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
PUB         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Pub name */
ODATE       DATE        NOT NULL,   /* Order date   */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
DRINK_NO    DECIMAL(2)  NOT NULL,   /* A sequence number of a drink */
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, PUB, ODATE, DRINK, DRINK_NO),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(PUB, DRINK) REFERENCES SERVES(PUB, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER)   );
```

Insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('BEER');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('RED WINE');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('WHITE WINE');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('CHAMPAGNE');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('VODKA');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('PORT');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('COGNAC');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('RUM');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('WHISKY');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('YABTSOK');
INSERT INTO ALLDRINKS VALUES('SPIRIT ROCKET');

INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('JANUSZ');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('PETER');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('MARY');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('JOHN');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('JAMES');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('SERGIEY');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('CLAUDE');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('MIKE');
INSERT INTO DRINKERS VALUES ('TOM');

INSERT INTO LOCATED VALUES('LAZY LOBSTER', 'STATION ST.', 45);
INSERT INTO LOCATED VALUES('GREASY FORK', 'VICTORIA AVE.', 345);
INSERT INTO LOCATED VALUES('CAPTAIN MOORE', 'KING ST.', 45);
INSERT INTO LOCATED VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'STATION ST.', 89);
INSERT INTO LOCATED VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'OXFORD ST.', 345);
INSERT INTO LOCATED VALUES('SWEET DREAMS', 'OXFORD ST.', 267);

INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LAZY LOBSTER', 'BEER', 5.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LAZY LOBSTER', 'RED WINE', 7.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LAZY LOBSTER', 'PORT', 8.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LAZY LOBSTER', 'COGNAC', 10.20);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LAZY LOBSTER', 'WHISKY', 6.90);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('GREASY FORK', 'BEER', 5.20); 
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('GREASY FORK', 'RED WINE', 7.40);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'BEER', 5.90);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'RED WINE', 8.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'WHITE WINE', 9.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'VODKA', 6.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'PORT', 9.35);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'COGNAC', 12.90);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LONG JOHN', 'WHISKY', 7.15);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'BEER', 4.50);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'RED WINE', 7.90);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'WHITE WINE', 5.40);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'CHAMPAGNE', 10.90);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'VODKA', 5.25);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'RUM', 12.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('LITTLE PIRATE', 'WHISKY', 10.80);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('SWEET DREAMS', 'BEER', 3.00);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('CAPTAIN MOORE', 'BEER', 4.50);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('SWEET DREAMS', 'RUM', 4.50);
INSERT INTO SERVES VALUES('SWEET DREAMS', 'YABTSOK', 4.50);

INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('TOM', 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'VODKA', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'RUM', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CHAMPAGNE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'RED WINE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'PORT', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'CHAMPAGNE', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'COGNAC', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'RUM', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'WHISKY', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('MARY', 'CHAMPAGNE', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('MARY', 'VODKA', 1);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('MARY', 'COGNAC', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'CHAMPAGNE', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'VODKA', 2);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'RUM', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JAMES', 'CHAMPAGNE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JAMES', 'COGNAC', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JAMES', 'RUM', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('SERGIEY', 'VODKA', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('SERGIEY', 'RUM', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('SERGIEY', 'CHAMPAGNE', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'CHAMPAGNE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'COGNAC', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'WHISKY', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'RED WINE', 6);

INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('8-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('8-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('9-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('11-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('13-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('15-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('16-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('17-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('18-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('01-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('02-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('03-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('05-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('06-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('15-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('16-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'CHAMPAGNE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('17-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'CHAMPAGNE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('20-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('22-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('01-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('05-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('01-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('02-MAY-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAY-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-MAY-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('01-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('02-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('8-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('9-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('11-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JUL-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('13-JUL-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JANUSZ', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('14-AUG-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('11-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('09-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'PORT', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('PETER', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 7);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('05-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('MARY', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('24-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('13-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 6);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('04-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JOHN', 'CAPTAIN MOORE', STR_TO_DATE('15-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'COGNAC', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'COGNAC', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'COGNAC', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('JAMES', 'SWEET DREAMS', STR_TO_DATE('23-JUN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('14-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('04-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('06-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('23-FEB-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('03-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('09-MAR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LITTLE PIRATE', STR_TO_DATE('04-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'VODKA', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'),'BEER', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('SERGIEY', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('10-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('15-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('15-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('19-JAN-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('04-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('05-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LAZY LOBSTER', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'GREASY FORK', STR_TO_DATE('20-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'BEER', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('12-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('15-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('16-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('17-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'WHITE WINE', 1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES('CLAUDE', 'LONG JOHN', STR_TO_DATE('19-APR-2020', '%d-%M-%Y'), 'RED WINE', 1);
```

Comment: Create statements for the other tables would be much appreciated. Either that or you can share a sqlfiddle with us http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I am a bit baffled by the apparent difference in the group by and order by , the order by dispenses with date entirely?

Comment: @jared I have updated the questions with the other tables and insert statements. I tried using the fiddle, but it told me the request was too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drink does not have to appear other than in the aggregate count, and the column order in the group by and order by is important. In the group by you want drinker within date and in the order by you want drinker within the count of drinks (you can use the alias here).

```
SELECT DRINKER, ODATE, COUNT(DRINK) obs
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY ODATE,DRINKER 
ORDER BY obs desc,DRINKER ASC
```